# Loading specific files from large data set in Python

Tags: python

I have a directory with around 300 files, all of which are numbered. I want to load every 10th file (...10.nii, ...20.nii, etc.), but am struggling to do so. Is there an easy method to do this?

Comment: show the exact layout, give us atleast 10 exact file names that you are using

Answer (score 1):

You could walk it and then check the filename. Something like this:

```
import os
for all in os.walk('/your/directory'):
    for f in all[2]:
        if f.endswith('0.nii'):
            print f
```

It might not be the easiest but it is fairly obvious what is going on. And that is the key! Even better and easier might be to use os.listdir instead.

See:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir

Comment: Thanks UlfR, this worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with glob module, even better than os in this case.
If the search is correct '*0.nii' then you need only one line to get what you need.

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('*0.nii'):
    print(file)
```

Please let me know if this solve your query.

Comment: Tried this as well as UlfR's suggestion above and both worked. Thanks